# Como evitar repetição em consultas LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Tenho a seguinte consulta LINQ que está em um método que retorna todos os produtos:

```
var query = from p in Produtos
    select new Produto
    {
        ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
        Descricao = p.Descricao,
        Preco = p.Preco,
        Estoque = p.Estoque
    };
return query;
```

Tenho também outros métodos que retornam os mesmos campos sendo que filtrados por determinadas condições ex:

```
var query = from p in Produtos
    where p.Descricao.StartsWith(descricao)
    select new Produto
    {
        ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
        Descricao = p.Descricao,
        Preco = p.Preco,
        Estoque = p.Estoque
    };
return query;
```

**Tem alguma maneira de evitar a repetição do trecho:**

> ```
>   select new Produto
>   {
>       ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
>       Descricao = p.Descricao,
>       Preco = p.Preco,
>       Estoque = p.Estoque
>
>   };
> ```
>
> Com isso, caso queira adicionar/remover algum campo, não teria que alterar todos os métodos.

Outras soluções também são bem vindas.

Comment: Tenta colocar dentro de um `switch statament`

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida fiquei curioso, por favor, mostre como é possível resolver isto com `switch`.

Comment: Achei este exemplo em C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405348/avoiding-repeating-code-with-linq-query-optional-params Eu usualmente programo em PHP (por isso não escrevi como resposta), mas as soluções podem ser aproximadas. Além do mais, sua solução parece mais elegante.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida na verdade nesse exemplo o `switch` está resolvendo outro problema, não o mesmo apresentado aqui e que é questionável se algo seria algo legal a se fazer em códigos modernos bem modularizados. A solução do problema apresentado lá é o mesmo daqui, mas não foi o `switch` que tornou ele possível. foi a separação do que é um padrão repetitivo do que variava.

Comment: Mas essa é a ideia. Eu digo o que quero e o `switch` diz como o LINQ tem que fazer. Os parâmetros são enviados para a consulta somente se atenderem uma condição definida no `switch`. Se eu passar isso pro controller não tem problema nenhum, afinal, o controller define o comportamento do meu sistema por meio de estruturas de decisão e o `switch` tá aí pra isso.

Comment: Só tem esses campos na tabela?

Comment: É apenas um exemplo ilustrativo, poderia ter mais campos. O intuito da pergunta é exatamente evitar problema de repetição de código caso seja necessário adicionar mais campos. @GOKUSSJ4

Comment: @rubStackOverflow. Veja o exemplo que respondi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se atende totalmente o que precisa porque o código apresentado está muito sem contexto, teria sido mais fácil se tivesse colocado um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Mas acho que isto resolve:

```
public static IEnumerable<Produto> Lista(IEnumerable<Produto> produtos) {
    return from p in produtos
        select new Produto {
            ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
            Descricao = p.Descricao,
            Preco = p.Preco,
            Estoque = p.Estoque
        };
}
public static IEnumerable<Produto> FiltreNome(IEnumerable<Produto> produtos, string descricao) {
    var query = from p in produtos
        where p.Descricao.StartsWith(descricao)
        select p;
    return Lista(query);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1bvir9). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dF5uVM). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/General.cs).

Comment: Entendido, na próxima vou procurar atender ao padrão [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma seria:

```
private static Produto CamposProduto(Produto p)
{
    return new Produto
    {
        ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
        Descricao = p.Descricao,
        Preco = p.Preco,
        Estoque = p.Estoque
    };
}
```

Para pegar os campos ficaria:

```
var query = from p in Produtos
    select CamposProduto(p);
return query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um DISCTINT() no final do select

ficarima mais ou menos assim:

```
var query = from p in Produtos
    where p.Descricao.StartsWith(descricao)
    select new Produto
    {
        ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
        Descricao = p.Descricao,
        Preco = p.Preco,
        Estoque = p.Estoque
    }.DISCTINT();
return query;
```

Espero que isso ajude

Comment: A repetição que eu me refiro, consta no corpo da pergunta, são os campos da consulta e não o resultado da mesma. @dacassussua

Answer (score 0):

Se seu objetivo é retorna apenas alguns campo de sua tabela você pode utilizar [Métodos de extensão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx), que funcionar como se você estivesse usando qualquer um outro método do Linq, sendo que você ainda tem a facilidade de usar quantos filtros precisar onde você fizer consulta e criar lista tipada ainda ou deixa [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397696.aspx)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class BuscarProdutos : Page
    {
        protected void Load_Produtos()
        {
            using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
            {
                var query =  ctx.Produtos
                    .Where(p => p.Descricao.StartsWith("descricao")) // aqui você pode por quantos filtros forem necessarios.
                    .Vw_Produto(ctx); // aqui você chama seu Métodos de extensão. (Vw_Produto)

                // enquanto a query for um IQueryable você pode fazer filtro tipo
                bool campo1 = true, campo2 = true;
                if(campo1 == campo2)
                {
                    query = query.Where(p => p.ProdutoId == 1);
                }

                // para execulta sua query user o ToList(); ou em algum tipo de loop, isso lançara uma consulta 
                // no banco de dados
                var lista = query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class cvw_Produto
    {
        public string Descricao { get; internal set; }
        public int? Estoque { get; internal set; }
        public decimal? Preco { get; internal set; }
        public int ProdutoId { get; internal set; }
    }

    public static class ProdutoExt
    {
        public static IQueryable<cvw_Produto> Vw_Produto(
                this IQueryable<Produto> qrIn, stackoverflowEntities ctx)
        {
            return qrIn
                .Select(p => new cvw_Produto // Com tipo ou deixe só o new para ficar tipo anonimos.
                {
                    ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
                    Descricao = p.Descricao,
                    Preco = p.Preco,
                    Estoque = p.Estoque
                });
        }
    }
}
```